# ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv3d_8 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 4, 150, 150]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a 3D CNN model in Keras, but i'm getting this error when I execute the cell:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv3d_8 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 4, 150, 150]
```

My input data is a numpy array with image data. Here are the shapes (I know that 53 is too few, but it's just for studying purposes):

```
Training data shape:  (53, 4, 150, 150)
Training labels shape:  (53, 1)
Validation data shape:  (14, 4, 150, 150)
Validation labels shape:  (14, 1)
```

The model I'm trying to use is:

```
# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=(4,150,150)))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
# Fit data to model
history = model.fit(treino3d, treino3d_labels,
            epochs=40)
```

Can someone help, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you need `Conv3D` layers for this task. Use `Conv2D` instead, and use only 1 or 2 values in `kernel_size` and `pool_size`.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', 
                 kernel_initializer='he_uniform', 
                 input_shape=(4,150,150)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', 
                 kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

Your channel dimension comes first so you will need to tell Keras. Use this line:

```
tf.keras.backend.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
```

Or set this parameter in every `Conv2D` or `MaxPooling2D` layer:

```
data_format='channels_first'
```

Or permute the dimensions of the input tensor to have shape `(54, 150, 150, 4)`:

```
np.transpose(x, (0, 2, 3, 1))
```

Full functioning, corrected example:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

xtrain = np.random.rand(53, 4, 150, 150)
ytrain = np.random.randint(0, 4, (53, 1))

xtrain = np.transpose(xtrain, (0, 2, 3, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',
                 kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=xtrain.shape[1:]))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',
          kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=1)
```

```
32/53 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 1.8215 - acc: 0.2812
53/53 [==============================] - 5s 91ms/sample - loss: 1.9651 - acc: 0.2264
```

Comment: Nicolas, thanks a lot for your answer. The data are actually medical imagens, so each of 4 channels represents a slice of an exam.

Anyway, I tried to run your suggestion with keras backend option, received the following error:

ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible

Comment: You need another dimension to use `Conv3D`. If your data has only 4, `Conv3D` isn't what you're looking for

Comment: You might have gone wrong somewhere. Please refer to my example above. It works.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you... Tried your example, keep causing the same error. The problem might be may labels array: array([3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3,
       1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 2])

Comment: Ah, my bad. Your labels aren't one-hot encoded. It should work now, I edited the code.

Comment: That error is gone, tks! But I'm getting a new one haha. Don't now if it's because I'm trying to run it at Colab. InvalidArgumentError:  InvalidArgumentError:  Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU
  [[node sequential_29/max_pooling2d_30/MaxPool (defined at <ipython-input-135-1f68d9fdfce1>:31) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_18392]

Function call stack:
train_function. Any idea?

Comment: I must admit, I didn't know `MaxPooling2D` had this restriction. As you can imagine, `NHWC` means _number of samples, height, width, channels_ and so it seems that you have to put the channels last. I changed my example. My apologies, as I use GPU.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I just changed the Colab environment to GPU and everything worked well! Thanks a lot, Nicolas!

Answer (score 1):

1. The first answer is correct. As I can recall (I didn't work with MRI for a couple of years), each slice is represented by 4 channels and each voxel in channel contains an information about the same physical position. Therefore, it would be correct approach to apply 2D-convolution for the image of 4 channels.
2. For 2D convolution I would recommend to define your input with input_shape=**(150,150,4)**, or even as input_shape=(None, None, 4) - it is more generic. So you don't need to play with *channel_first* or *channel_last* configuration. **channel_last** is  default format, as I remember
3. If you insist to use Conv3d, your input shape should be: input_shape=**(150,150,4,1)** or **(None, None, None, 1)**
   and trainset should follow shape like: **np.random.rand(53, 150, 150, 4, 1)**

Comment: Yuri, thanks a lot for your answer and explanations! I managed to make Nicolas' solution work! Thank you!